# Does Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 Contain Gnome Classic Session?

Tags: gnome, command-line, 13.04

If I understand right, Ubuntu-GNOME will be using GNOME 3. I was wondering if it also included Gnome Classic as well, or if I would have to go download it?

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu GNOME 13.04 won't have Gnome Classic (gnome-session-fallback) preinstalled.
But you will be able to install Gnome Classic using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

It will ship with GNOME Shell 3.6 only.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 13.04 will only have Unity included. As for Gnome Classic, its maintenance [has been dropped](https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointSeven/Features/DropOrFixFallbackMode) by the Gnome Foundation, but you may be able to use the [new Classic Mode](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/a-quick-look-at-new-gnome-classic.html) in future releases of [Ubuntu Gnome](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/ubuntu-gnome-1304-daily-images.html).
The new Classic Mode will be available in Gnome 3.8.

Comment: He's not talking about regular Ubuntu. He talking about Ubuntu GNOME, which won't have Unity installed, as it'll have GNOME instead. This was stated in both the question and the title.